# sinusoidal signal with varying frequency

Tags: matlab, simulink

I want to generate a variable frequency sinusoidal signal. I am changing the frequency from 0Hz to 30Hz, but the frequency sine output increases above 30Hz during first 1 second simulation and finally after 1 second the frequency settles down to 30Hz.

Please suggest me why the frequency of the sine wave not following the frequency.
[image]

[image]

Comment: Because of the slope of the ramp (FREQUENCY).

Comment: Not sure why this has been voted to be closed.  The OP has provided a model and given an image of the problematic output. That's far more than most new posters.  If this isn't suitable then no Simulink question has ever been suitable.

Comment: Be aware that the [Chirp](https://www.mathworks.com/help/dsp/ref/chirp.html) block does exactly what you are trying to do.  If you right click on a Chirp block, then about half way down the subsequent menu select `Mask->Look Under Mask` you'll can see how it is implemented.

Comment: For chirp block, the initial and final frequency needs to be preset. But my job is to change the sinusoidal frequency with reference to the output from pid controller which varies during the simulation.

Comment: Ander biguri, I know the ramp input is causing the output to change likewise...but the frequency increases  beyond 30 hz initially for 1 sec ..... N finally settles to 30 hz. How can I get sine wave as per the frequency value.

Answer (score 0):

It because of simulation ***Sample time*** , It is one second.

Change the Sample time to a small number such as 0.01

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you misread some parameters of chirp usage, particularly `target frequency` and `target time`.

When you work with a `swept cosine` sweep, target frequency will be reached at half of target time. So if you set `target frequency = 30 Hz` and `target time = 1 s` you will have 30 Hz at 0.5 s and 60 Hz at 1 s.

From Matlab documentation:

> Target frequency is the instantaneous frequency of the output **at half the Target time, tg/2.**
>
> Target time is the time at which **the sweep reaches 2*f(tg)**.